# Code is not working. Using Stacks

Tags: c++

Here's my code for checking balanced parenthesis which takes an expression and checks if user entered the expression correctly but it isn't working. It gives an error. I don't think so there is an error in the public thing.
Please Help!

```
class dynamicStack {
    struct node{
        char num;
        node *next;
    };
    public:
    node *top;
    dynamicStack(){
        top=NULL;
    }
    void push(char);
    void pop();
    void check(string);
};

void check(string exp) {
    \\some code
}
void dynamicStack::pop(){
    node *temp;
    temp=top;
    if(top == NULL)  {
        cout<<"Stack is empty"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Deleting number: "<<temp->num<<endl;
    top=top->next;
    delete temp;
}

void dynamicStack::push(char c) {
    node *newNode;
    newNode = new node;
    newNode->num=c;
    newNode->next=top;
    top=newNode;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  {
    dynamicStack dS;
    string exp;
    cout<<"Enter an expression:  ";
    cin>>exp;
    dS.check(exp);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
     1>ds-2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void                    _thiscall dynamicStack::check(class std::basic_string<char,struct                      std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?    check@dynamicStack@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
```

Comment: I think your code copy failed, its really hard to read

Comment: Your implementation of `void check(string exp) { /* etc */ }`  should start with `void dynamicStack::check(string exp)  { /* etc */ }`

Comment: What's wrong with `std::stack`?

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked :) @AdrianColomitchi

Comment: Is there any logical mistake?

Comment: "It worked :)" If you indent your code properly, it will be easier to detect if you are inside the class definition or outside it.

Comment: Its been a long time i didnt use c++ so i just forgot the syntax.

Comment: "so i just forgot the syntax" And yet, you remembered it for push and pop.

Comment: I copied it .. there's an logical error aswell. Check once again please @AdrianColomitchi

Comment: example code is still hard to read.

Comment: "there's an logical error aswell." That's another question: **don't mix them up**, or the entire set of answers are going to suddenly look wrong with your new version of the question. Besides, what a debugger is good for?

Comment: Okay @AdrianColomitchi i deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of

```
void check(string exp)
```

does not mention its class scope. It must read:

```
void dynamicStack::check(string exp) {
...
}
```

BTW this is exactly what the linker message is trying to tell you. When you are getting these kind of errors you often simply got something like the above wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`Member functions` (function `check` in you program) can be defined within the class definition or separately outside the class using `scope resolution operator`, **::**. If you want to define some function outside the class, you can do it using scope resolution operator, :: as follows:

```
void dynamicStack :: check(string exp)
{
    //Do something
}
```

In your program, you have forgotten scope resolution operator for function `check()`. The error that you have provided (`unresolved external symbol`) is because you have been calling member function of `dS` object using `ds.check()` but the compiler didn't find implementation of member function `check()`. The function definition without scope resolution operator is being treated as a separate function.

**Defining a member function within the class definition declares the function inline, even if you do not use the inline specifier.**